# Time format (%"Y") in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to put my data into a template, the code is here
data is seen from line 32 - line 46.

```
        var myData = "date,Heritage,Museum,Art
```

However they have manually inputted the data in the script and it took a long time to enter it each time. Is there anyway I can use

```
     d3.csv("name.csv")
```

here so that it loads the csv file from a local file? I've seen people use it in tutorials but cannot figure out how to link it to the rest of the script.

Many Thanks

Update:
After using v5 the format is undefined:

```
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
```

Comment: Are you using d3.js v5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using v5 of D3.js, you can import local CSV files by going something like this:

```
d3.csv("/path/to/file.csv").then(data => {
  console.log(data); // [{"Hello": "world"}, …]
});
```

You will be able to access the data extracted from your CSV file within the `then()` block. As you can see from the above example, when you `console.log()` it, you should be able to see the full data from your CSV. You may read more about it over [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#csv).

```js
d3.csv("/path/to/file.csv").then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 100,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);
    
  // add the rest of the code here
});
```

As for your updated question, there are many syntax changes since you have upgraded from V3 to V5.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse
```

should be changed to

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");
```

You may refer to the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for the full migration guide.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this, now it's saying d3.csv(...).then is not a function and myData is not defined.

Comment: @Elle May I know which D3.js version are you on

Comment: Hi sorry it was using v3, I have changed it to v5 and the array did load, however format is not working. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined at linechart.html:46

Comment: @Elle Ok ermm.. If you have upgraded it from V3 to V5, there  are a lot of changes in terms of syntax.

Comment: For instance, on your line 46.. `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;` should be changed to `var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");` instead. Let me explain on the answer instead. Let me know if that works?

Comment: I see, there are lots to change I will go through the changelog. Thank you so much!